# How to change the font of all Toolbar Items in Navigation Header in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, font-awesome, uibarbuttonitem

I have created a custom navigation page in xamarin in order to change the font of the toolbar items in the navigation bar.

All went well, however the font is not changing on all toolbar items, just the last one for some reason.

[image: Icons]

As you can see, I have also tried to change the color to red, apart from the font however this is only working on the last item aswell.

XAML:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="MenuItem1"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Text="x1"
                 Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="MenuItem2"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Text="x2"
                 Priority="1" />
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="MenuItem3"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Text="x3"
                 Priority="2" />
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="MenuItem4"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Text="x4"
                 Priority="3" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

iOS:

```
public class FontAwesomeNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var att = new UITextAttributes
            {
                Font = UIFont.FromName("FontAwesome5Pro-Light", 18),
                TextColor = UIColor.Red
            };

            UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(att, UIControlState.Normal);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered using DynamicResource instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working thanks to some help from @iSpain17 in the comment above.

Below is my code for the iOS part

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated) {
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

    SetNavigationButtonsPage();
}

private void SetNavigationButtonsPage()
{
    var att = new UITextAttributes
    {
        Font = UIFont.FromName("FontAwesome5Pro-Light", 16),
    };

    var navigationItems = (this as UINavigationController).NavigationBar.Items;
    List<UIBarButtonItem> barButtonItems = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

    foreach (UINavigationItem item in navigationItems)
    {
        barButtonItems.AddRange(item.LeftBarButtonItems);
        barButtonItems.AddRange(item.RightBarButtonItems);
    }

    foreach (UIBarButtonItem bbItem in barButtonItems)
    {
        //change appearance for each bbItem
        bbItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(att, UIControlState.Normal);
    }
}
```

The solution was to change the method being used from OnElementChanged to ViewDidAppear!

Thank You :)

Comment: I'm happy you made it work :) And yes, ViewDidAppear only gets called at the right time, OnElementChanged will be called multiple times while setting up the Element I think (and also later during the lifetime of the element).

Answer (score 1):

NavigationRenderer [is a UINavigationController in iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/NavigationRenderer.cs), so you can do the following:

```
var navController = this as UINavigationController;
var navigationItems = navController.NavigationBar.Items)
List<UIBarButtonItem> barButtonItems = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

foreach(UINavigationItem item in navigationItems) {
    barButtonItems.AddRange(item.NavigationBar.leftBarButtonItems);
    barButtonItems.AddRange(item.NavigationBar.rightBarButtonItems);
}

foreach(UIBarButtonItem bbItem in barButtonItems) {
    //change appearance for each bbItem
}
```

This will list every `UINavigationItem` for this `UINavigationController`, and then take every `UIBarButtonItem` associated with them.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it out and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, the navigationItems variable is always empty. :/

Comment: Well that is rather weird. Can you check the TopItem property? As that should be the one for the page currently presented